# Are there any other functions that behave the same as $ce^x$ with respect to differentiation

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{d}{dx} ce^x = ce^x$$
Are there any other functions $f$ such that
$$\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = f(x)$$
or is $ f(x) = ce^x $ the only one?

Comment: Trivial function $f(x)=0$ also works.

Comment: That corresponds to $c=0$.

Comment: The answer depends on your domain... If the domain is disconected, the answer is no ;)

Comment: @N.S. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: If your domain is $(-\infty,0) \cup (0, \infty)$ for example, on each of these intervals you get a function of your type, but the constants can be different.

Comment: What do you mean by the constants will be different? Wouldn't you get the function $ce^x$, but defined on the domain $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$ when you differentiate it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No: If $f$ were such a function, consider $g(x) = f(x) e^{-x}$. Then

$$g'(x) = f'(x) e^{-x} + f(x) (-e^{-x}) = f(x) e^{-x} - f(x) e^{-x} = 0$$

As a result, $g$ is constant.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the first order differential equation $$f'(x)=f(x)$$ which is separable. It's integration leads to $$f(x)=c e^x$$ and this is the only possible solution.